# Sending JSON and File in same multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ng-file-upload

I have a form with an image and fields that I want to submit.

I'm running into problems since my POST request has content-type multipart/form-data and not JSON. 
For example, any `null` values in my form are converted to "null" string...

Is it a bad practice ton send JSON and files in the same request ?

Perhaps I should decompose my POST in 2 seperate ones ?

One for the file in multipart/form-data

One for the JSON in application/json

Comment: It is possible to send both form data and files, but not JSON. I think just make your server process filter out the nulls and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To Expand @Mikkel's answer - you can write the following code to parse the JSON sent as string:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
app.post('/multipart', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    console.log('multipart API was called.');
    console.log(req.body);
    var bodyAsJson = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
    console.log(bodyAsJson);
    // some other multipart code...
});
```